# Not able to print value of object in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I have an object in Angular2 as below:

```
userDetails = {"userId":23,"first_name":"Rajesh","last_name":"Kumar"}
```

Now whenever I try to print value of **userDetails.first_name** in html file then there is an error on browser

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'first_name' of undefined.
```

Please help me to understand the root cause.

Comment: Can you please add more details to this ? like you have created any model for userDetails, code where you are using this userDetails.
try printing object in console before using.

Comment: I am calling a backend API to get this value . I am using this value in a component . Value of this object in console is Object {first_name: "Rakesh", last_name: "Kumar", profile_summary: "This is my Summary", email: "test", mobile: "1234567890"} .

Comment: did you try with json.parse(userDetails) . Have a look on below examples: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40205621/5527977  OR https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Comment: Yes I have already done that.

Comment: Did you initialize userDetails?? please define it in the component as `private userDetails = {}`

Comment: Working Fine after initialising userDetails . Thanks guys !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your object **userDetails** is not Defined, that is why you are getting this error , try to console the value of userDetails & check whether it's returning empty value or not. Do share your response.